# how to remove a child object by removeChild()?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, event-listener, removechild

I'm trying to make a custom animated/shooter, from this tutorial: http://flashadvanced.com/creating-small-shooting-game-as3/

By custom, I mean customized, ie, my own version of it.

In it's actionscript, there's a timer event listener with function: timerHandler()
This function adds and removes child "star" objects on the stage (which the user has to shoot at):

```
if(starAdded){
removeChild(star);
}
```

and :

```
addChild(star);
```

## Code works great, but error occurs on scene 2.

The code works great, and I even added some code while learning via google and stackflow to this flash file. I added Scene 2 to it too, and had it called after 9 seconds of movie time. But when it goes to Scene 2, it still displays the star objects and I've been unable to remove these "star" object(s) from Scene 2.

### Here's the code I added:

SCENE 1:

```
var my_timer = new Timer(5000,0); //in milliseconds
my_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, catchTimer);
my_timer.start();


var myInt:int = getTimer() * 0.001;
var startTime:int = getTimer();
var currentTime:int = getTimer();
var timeRunning:int = (currentTime - startTime) * 0.001; // this is how many seconds the game has been running.
demo_txt.text = timeRunning.toString();

function catchTimer(e:TimerEvent)
{
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
}
```

---

SCENE 2:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
function myFunction(event:Event) {
    timer.stop();
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
    stage.removeChild(star);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, cursorMoveHandler);
    my_timer.stop(); // you might need to cast this into Timer object
    my_timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, catchTimer);
    Mouse.show();
}
stop();
```

=====================================================

I'm quite new as3, and have just created an account on StackOverflow... even though I've known and read many codes on it since quite some time.

## Here's the Edited New Complete Code:

```
//importing tween classes
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.Tween;

//hiding the cursor
Mouse.hide();

//creating a new Star instance
var star:Star = new Star();
var game:Game = new Game();
//creating the timer
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
//we create variables for random X and Y positions
var randomX:Number;
var randomY:Number;
var t:int = 0;
//variable for the alpha tween effect
var tween:Tween;
//we check if a star instance is already added to the stage
var starAdded:Boolean = false;
//we count the points
var points:int = 0;

//adding event handler on mouse move
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, cursorMoveHandler);
//adding event handler to the timer
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
//starting the timer
timer.start();
addChild(game);
function cursorMoveHandler(e:Event):void{
    //sight position matches the mouse position
    game.Sight.x = mouseX;
    game.Sight.y = mouseY;
}

function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void{
    //first we need to remove the star from the stage if already added
    if(starAdded){
        removeChild(star);
    }

    //positioning the star on a random position
    randomX = Math.random()*500;
    randomY = Math.random()*300;
    star.x = randomX;
    star.y = randomY;
    //adding the star to the stage
    addChild(star);
    //changing our boolean value to true
    starAdded = true;
    //adding a mouse click handler to the star
    star.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
    //animating the star's appearance
    tween = new Tween(star, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 3, true);
t++;
if(t>=5) {
    gotoAndPlay(5);
}
}

function clickHandler(e:Event):void{
    //when we click/shoot a star we increment the points
    points ++;
    //showing the result in the text field
    points_txt.text = points.toString();
}
```

## And on Frame 5 :

```
//timer.stop();
    //timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
    // uncomment lines above if "timer" is something you've made
    stage.removeChild(star);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, cursorMoveHandler);
    timer.stop(); // you might need to cast this into Timer object
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
    Mouse.show();
    stop();
```

There's no Scene 2 now, in this new .fla file...
Here's a screenshot of the library property of my flash file...: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVJjm.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better drop scenes altogether, they are pretty much deprecated in AS3. Instead, use `Game` object that contains all the cursor, stars and other stuff that's inside the game, and instead of going with `gotoAndPlay()` do `removeChild(game); addChild(scoreboard);` where "scoreboard" is another container class that will display your score.

Regarding your code, you stop having a valid handle to `stage` that actually contains that `star` of yours, because your have changed the scene. So do all of this before calling `gotoAndPlay()` in your `catchTimer` function.

```
function catchTimer(e:TimerEvent)
{
    //timer.stop();
    //timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
    // uncomment lines above if "timer" is something you've made
    stage.removeChild(star);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, cursorMoveHandler);
    my_timer.stop(); // you might need to cast this into Timer object
    my_timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, catchTimer);
    Mouse.show();
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
}
```

And the code for Scene 2 will consist of a single `stop()` - until you'll add something there. Also, there should be no event listeners, especially enter-frame, without a code to remove that listener! You add an enter-frame listener on Scene 2 and never remove it, while you need that code to only run once.

Comment: I don't know/remember how to work with Classes and objects. If I create and convert the cursor, star into movie clips, and then group them in another movie clip, game... then how will I be able to add new stars to the stage?. " var star:Star = new Star(); //adds a new object variable Star form identifier in library. How do I call the "addChild(star);" if all the contents are wrapped in "game" movieclip? Should I group them anyways? And then Link the game.star to ac3 via identifier? Is yes, then how do I declare the star variable? var star:Star = new Star(); ??

Comment: Well, I grouped the star and cursor(sight) movie clips into another identifier Game movie clip, and this is how I changed the code **which didn't work again** .. var game:Game = new Game(); game.Sight.x = mouseX; removeChild(game.Star); game.Star.x = randomX; game.addEventListener...tween = new Tween(game.Star, "alpha",... _just copied the required code for, the rest of the code is only similar to that on the gamepage tutorial link (as shown in the question of this page)_

Comment: Please add edited code to the question (edit the question). Perhaps there's a typo that causes erroneous behavior.

Comment: See, the `star` object still has `stage` as parent, so a star won't be removed from display if you only remove `game`. Also, now your `star` gets added a click listener each timer tick - isn't it plain wrong, as you create `new Star()` only once? You create, add and let it be. Another nitpick - if your player will frantically click at the star, he'll get a whole lot of points, I guess the star should relocate each time it's clicked.

Comment: Ok.. so should I remove the Game object completely? So that only Star and pointer/sight remain? With that it will be back to the original working code with only problem that I cannot end the game.. for which you've suggested to relocate at clicks. So what part of the code should I move to the clickHandler?

Comment: You have a code in timer handler that moves the star, this part should be moved to click handler. And yes, if you use frames to display endgame, you don't need `Game` stuff.

Comment: I added this code to the click handler and it's much better now! Thanks! :D `if(starAdded)
 {
  removeChild(star);
  starAdded = false;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Use [getChildAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildAt%28%29).

```
    function catchTimer(e:TimerEvent)
    {
        var childCount:int = this.numChildren - 1;
        var i:int;
        var tempObj:DisplayObject;
        for (i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
        tempObj = this.getChildAt(i);
        this.removeChild(tempObj);
        }
        gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
    }
```

This will remove all the children you added on scene 1 before going to scene 2.

Comment: That removed the Star Object successfully... but didn't goto scene 2... I got a blank screen with no text or anything and even the mouse cursor wasn't showing!